# Potentiometer on max. resistance at lowest setting (off)

Tags: potentiometer, log

first question ever here:

I'm struggling with a 10K log potentiometer in an EQ. When at lowest CCW setting it's the same value as on full CW pos.

Is this typical when a pot goes bad or is that fixable?

**update:**

Thanks for the advice! I'll change the pot and maybe have a look at the wiper when I have it unsoldered.

**update:**

When measured [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WzxaD.jpg) between the wiper and one of the end terminals the resistance varies gradually (log), but after it goes down to 0 at CCW position it sometimes jumps to the max. value:[image: 5.66K] 
Which in this case is our Pultec EQ and results in full boost.[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k57No.jpg) 
We have a lot of people using our gear, so maybe someone just forced it and **broke it**.

Comment: This would be normal if you were measuring across the wrong two terminals (assuming you're reading 10K).   You need to measure between the wiper and one of the end terminals.

Comment: The resistance between the end terminals is constant, regardless of setting.  The resistance between the wiper/moving contact/center terminal varies as you adjust the pot.

Answer (score 4):

Share the part number or picture of your potentiometer.

[image]

If you measure resistance between **A** and **B** it will always be 10 kohm. Point **C** is called wiper end and you should be ideally using

**A** and **C**

or

**B** and **C**

terminals if you need to varying resistance.

Comment: Your answer is correct for an open circuit pot. Results when measuring in circuit with pot still connected could be quite different.

Answer (score 1):

If you struggled with pot and only connect 2 pins failure would be open circuit.

There should be some minimum resistance like 1%,  not Zero . If you forced it to try to get 0, but now get 10k, **you broke it.**

If you have tap pin,  also connected to CW pin , that would explain the open circuit =10k .

Conclusion: Bust Pot.  Unlikely repairable wiper but possible.